# Primefaces fileUpload what happens to file if it is not saved locally

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jboss

Quick question. In case I choose not to save an uploaded file locally before utilizing it, I know it gets saved to temp of the server. Does it get auto deleted? Is that (deletion time) something I need to configure in the server (Jboss 6.4 as of this writing). Further, is that location also something that I need to configure in web.xml?

Thank you
Karthik

Comment: did you try something please see this post [How to upload a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964)

Comment: to give more details about your question it's true that when you try to upload a file ifyou don't set the file location the system will choose a temp folder to send the file to